Pumping Lemma for regular languages
Considering the language $L=\{a^nb \;|\; n \ge 0\}$. This is a regular language since it can be recognized by this automaton:

So, the pumping lemma should be satisfied, However

If I take my pumping constant $p=1$
the smaller string possible is $w=b\;\;\;$ ($|w| \ge p$ is satisfied)
The only possible way for $xy$ is $xy=b\;\;\;$($|xy| \le p$ is satisfied)
The only possible way for $y$ is $y=b\;\;\;$($|y| \ge 1$ is satisfied)
$y^i$ when $i=0$ is $\;\varepsilon\;$. And $\;\varepsilon\;$ does not belong to $L$, so the lemma is not satisfied.

I missunderstood something for sure. What the lemma states for $p$?

For all $p$ the conditions should be satisfied; or
At least one $p$ should satisfy the conditions

Thanks

(Please correct the title.) It may be a good idea to state the pumping lemma for regular languages in the form you want to argue about.

The statement of the pumping lemma start with the following:

For every regular language $L$ there exists a constant $p>0$ such that...

So in order for the language to satisfy the pumping lemma, there must exist some constant, but it might fail for other (smaller) constants.
If you examine the proof of the lemma, you'll see that $p$ is taken to be the number of states in an automaton for $L$. Indeed -- words longer than the number of states guarantee that an accepting run has a cycle, from which we can obtain the lemma.
So in this case you'd need at least $p=2$.

Really appreciate your help for thi: https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/170315/161834.
