Pumping lemma in a regular language
Following this question: Considering the regular language $L=\{a^nb \;|\; n \ge 0\}$ and trying to apply the pumping lemma (I know in advance that the lemma should be satisfied as $L$ is regular)

Taking $p=2$
The smallest possible string will be $w=ab$
$y$ will ever contain $b$
Taking $y=b$ and pumping $y^0$ results in $w=a$ which is not in $L$

I mean: for any $p \ge 1$, the smallest possible string will be: $ a^{p-1}b $. In any case, $y$ will contain $b$. So making $y=b$ and pumping it to $0$, the pumped string will not contain a $b$ hence will never belong to $L$, so, in base of this, there is no $p$ that satisfies the lemma. So I must say that $L$ is not regular. However, I know that $L$ es regular since I can drow a DFA.
I have a really big mess. Thanks for your help!.

wait, choosing particular decomposition of string for which property isn't satisfied isn't correct approach, there should exist at least 1 such decomposition of string. so you shouldn't search for decomposition which wouldn't work, you should search for decomposition that will work for any i>=0 pump.

For p=2 and taking w=ab and y=b, what is the property that is not satisfied?

For any word $w$ of length $\geqslant p = 2$, $w = a^nb$ with $n\geqslant 1$.
Then choose $x = \varepsilon$, $y = a$ and $z= a^{n-1}b$.
For any $k\geqslant 0$, $xy^kz = a^{n+k-1}b\in L$.
You cannot choose $y = b$, because, as you pointed out, this is not a valid decomposition. (I don't understand why you said "$y$ will ever contain $b$")

"I don't understand why you said y will ever contain b" me neither tbh!. Thank you so much

The pumping lemma for regular languages can only be used to prove that a language is not regular (more precisely: Is not recognised by any finite state machine, but that's equivalent).
All you can do for a regular language is to attempt to prove its irregular by using the pumping lemma, and then see why your proof failed. For irregular languages proofs often fail because you were not clever enough, for regular languages proofs always fail because you can never prove that a regular language is irregular.
